# Using DataGrid in WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, datagrid

I need to show my data in a datagrid. I am using following code:

Front End:

Namespace:`xmlns:datagrid="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Data"`

```
 <datagrid:DataGrid Name="tgrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  Grid.Row="2"  HeadersVisibility="Column">
            <datagrid:DataGrid.Columns>
                <datagrid:DataGridTextColumn Header="Name">

                </datagrid:DataGridTextColumn>
            </datagrid:DataGrid.Columns>
        </datagrid:DataGrid>
```

Backend:

```
        List<LItem> str = new List<LItem>();
        str.Add(new LItem() { Str = "chandra" });
        str.Add(new LItem() { Str = "chandra" });
        str.Add(new LItem() { Str = "chandra" });
        str.Add(new LItem() { Str = "chandra" });
        str.Add(new LItem() { Str = "chandra" });
        str.Add(new LItem() { Str = "chandra" });
        tgrid.ItemsSource = str;

    public class LItem
    {
        private string _str;

        public string Str
        {
            get { return _str; }
            set { _str = value; }
        }
    }
```

When I use this code I get a exception as:

```
The type 'projectName.MainPage', specified in the x:Class of '/MainPage.xaml' could not be found in any loaded assembly.
```

Answer (score 2):

The exception you have shown appears to be related to some XAML which you have not shown. the `x:Class` attached property indicates the code-behind class for a user control. Does the type `projectName.MainPage` exits in your project?

I would recommend starting over again with a new user control, slowing adding back your code, re-compiling and running as you slowly add code back.

Comment: projectName.MainPage exists in my project. When I comment the datagrid part, the program executes as usual.